# Visual Studio 2013 Web Deployment Package failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, deployment

MS deployment service was started. I tried the [web deployment package method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx) and the .zip file was generated along with .deploy.cmd and the xml setting files.

As per the .deploy.cmd file, (planning to host the application on localhost) I tried the command

C:\Project>ProjectName.deploy.cmd /T /L /M:http://localhost/MSDeployAgentService

Dint get any errors for the above command. Got the prompt as "Creating application" and all the project files were copied.

When I changed the arguments from /T to /Y as said in ProjectName.deploy-readme.txt (generated as a part of ProjectName.deploy.cmd), I faced the below error. Please let me know if I had missed any. Since this is my first application which I am publishing, your suggestions/comments will help me to fix this issue.

**ERROR:**
C:\Project>ProjectName.deploy.cmd /Y /L /M:http://localhost/MSDeployAgentService
SetParameters from:
"C:\Project\ProjectName.SetParameters.xml"
You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString or other deploy parameters in the above file.

---

Start executing msdeploy.exe

---

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C:\Project\ProjectName.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="http://localhost/MSDeployAgentService",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\Project\ProjectName.SetParameters.xml"  -appHostConfigDir:"C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\IISExpress\config" -WebServerDir:"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\" -webServerManifest:"iisexpress.exe.manifest"
Info: Using ID 'd7a7b830-175c-4ec7-9baa-5d01db271c30' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Creating application (Default Web Site/MyApplication)
Info: Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/MyApplication)
Error: (2/17/2016 11:17:19 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonAcl.ThrowIfNotCanonical()
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonAcl.Purge(SecurityIdentifier sid)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor.PurgeAccessControl(SecurityIdentifier sid)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity.PurgeAccessRules(IdentityReference identity)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SetAclProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Update(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
Error count: 1.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was fixed after few surfings.

opened Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. In the left pane, you can find connections tab and if the deployment simulation has worked (the command with :/T), then you should find your application copied <User> -> Sites -> MyApplication.

Right click MyApplication, select Edit Permissions -> Security -> you might get a pop up saying "Permissions on <APP> are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some entries to be ineffective". Click OK and click Advanced button.

Click Change Permissions and you might get another pop up to reorder. Click reorder, and exit.

Now try the above mentioned command and it works.!